# XPath SelectNodes

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have:

```
<div id="foo">
<a href="/xxx.php"> xx </a>
<a href="/xy.php"> xy </a>
<a href="/uid.php?id=123"> 123 </a>
<a href="/uid.php?id=344"> 344 </a>
</div>
```

I how select only items containing 'id' in href using HtmlAgilityPack?

with Output:

```
 <a href="/uid.php?id=123"> 123 </a>
    <a href="/uid.php?id=344"> 344 </a>
```

Thanks,Advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following xpath expression should select all `a` elements that have an `href` tag that contains the text "id".

```
var xpathExpression = "//a[contains(@href, 'id')]";
```

I was able to select the a tags with id in the href attribute using the following code:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(
  @"<div id=""foo"">
    <a href=""/xxx.php""> xx </a>
    <a href=""/xy.php""> xy </a> 
    <a href=""/uid.php?id=123""> 123 </a>
    <a href=""/uid.php?id=344""> 344 </a>
</div>");
var aTags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[contains(@href, 'id')]");
foreach(var aTag in aTags)
Console.WriteLine(aTag.OuterHtml);
```

Comment: Slightly easier syntax: `//a[contains(@href, 'id')]`